# php exec keeps loading

Tags: php, exec

im working on some code to run a .bat file but for some reason the bat the page keeps loading

```html
<?php if (!empty($_POST)){ 
$myfile = fopen("search.bat", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$loc = $_POST["loc"];
$txt = "my bat code";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
exec("search.bat");
echo "seaching";
}



else{ ?>
    <form action=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?> method="post">
        loc: <input type="text" name="loc"><br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
<?php }; ?>
```

Comment: instead of  `!empty($_POST) ` , try  `isset($_POST)`

Comment: untill you close search.bat, php file will keep loading